# Pressure at a depth in Huge water mass

Tags: pressure, liquid-state

I am trying to ask my doubt by converting it into a example problem but i am really not able to do so properly- heres my best attempt at it:-

The pressure at a certain depth(~ 1km) in a ocean ,a gigantic one (total depth~100 km), i think is created from 2 different forces

*1. The downward   force due to weight of   ocean water above that specified depth and
2.The downward Gravitational pull from the mass of ocean water(below the specified depth) itself.*

But i doubt that the factor 2 is not responsible due to some book problems that i have been solving recently.So are both factors responsible? or is it just the 1st one? (Neglect any other small forces, only if they are small)

Also mass of water is so huge that its gravtational pull can't be neglected so that cannot be the reason that factor 2 is not responsible for pressure at a certain depth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your factor 1) is by definition all there is to account for. This "downward force due to weight" is coming from the gravitational pull from everything below  that depth. This automatically includes the water below it, the rock, the magma, everything. It doesn't tell you which fraction of the weight is coming from each of those different substances, but they are included in what you call the weight  in factor 1).

So under no circumstances do you need to subsequently add the pull from the mass of ocean water below the specified depth, as you try to do in factor 2). That would be counting the same thing twice.

Maybe you do want to know what fraction of the weight is coming from the different layers. In the case of an idealized spherically symmetric layered structure, all the layers below the specified depth contribute, and they contribute according to the total mass they contain as if that mass was in the center of the planet. That is equivalent to electric charge: just the total charge within a certain radius gives the $E$-field at that radius.

So for the contribution of some layer of water below the specified depth, you need to look at the water in an *entire shell* surrounding the planet with the thickness of that water layer, and the mass in that shell is all you need to know. (Usually that still will be less mass than the entire interior of the planet, but on a water planet it all depends on where the specified depth is.)

This is all focussing at the gravity at some depth, but to find the pressure in your question you need a complete line of points towards the surface and the gravity will change along that line, especially if you start very deep. It may go up or down. For a pure water planet it goes up with height, because more mass becomes included below your position. But for a planet with relatively heavy substance in the core, the pull of gravity might decrease with height because larger distance to that haevy stuff makes more difference than getting more water below you.

Answer (score 2):

Your factor 2 should definitely be negligible, compared to 1, and would also *decrease* the force with depth. Partially this is due to your wording.

Yes, the ocean water below has some mass, and thus attraction. But as you go deeper into the water, less and less of that mass is below you.  At roughly half the depth, the gravity from the water below would be cancelled out by the gravity of the water above.  When at the bottom of the ocean, the gravity *due to water* would decrease, as now that mass is all above you.

I did mention though that this is partially due to your wording.  If you consider the effect of *Earth's* gravity as you get deeper, the picture reverses.  Earth's gravity is actually higher at the ocean floor than at the top of the water.  This is because water and upper layers of crust are less dense than the mantle near the core of the Earth.

Even then though, the change in Earth's gravity will cause some increase in pressure at depth, but nowhere near as great of an effect as all the water pushing down on it.  The change in gravity is practically negligible.

Comment: Actually in the original problem there was a planet made only of water and pressure at a certain depth was to be found. This changes 2 things--  1) That as we go deep down to approximately half of depth of planet the graviational pull from upper half and lower half water mass doesn't cancel out now because we know the upper half will form a shell and gravitation pull due to a shell mass is 0 like electric field inside conductor is 0.   2) The radius of an average planet example earth is ~ 6000 km if i measure depth at ~ 50 km will the gravitation pull from water mass below still be negligible?

Comment: Can you just describe the original problem exactly? You keep asking different questions and then changing them,  but of course we are becoming very curious about what this water planet was!

Comment: @JosBergervoet I apologise for your trouble, i was thinking that if i ask the original problem then that question might get blocked due to rules of this site but as it turned out it still got blocked :(

Comment: Not to worry! We are now discussing basic concepts and their meaning, which is on topic for the forum, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Factor 2 is normally ignored. When we calculate the pressure at a depth of 1 km we want know the crushing compression force on e.g. a submarine and this a different thing to the force drawing the submarine downwards that we normally call the weight of the submarine.

**The weight of the submarine is actually reduced by having 99 km of water below it, because water has a lower mass density than the rock that would otherwise be below it.**

Because there is effectively less gravity at a given depth in a deep ocean than in a shallow ocean, the weight of the water column above the submarine is lower and so the pressure at a given depth is less in the deeper ocean.